# Invoke-Sqlcmd not working after PowerShell 4 install

Tags: windows, sql-server, powershell-4.0

I installed PowerShell 4 yesterday and ever since then, I get the error "The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function".

This has been working just fine for months until PowerShell 4.

I have SQL 2012 SP1 installed with CU7. VS 2013 with .NET 4.5.1.  As far as I can tell, I have all the latest everything that PowerShell requires.

How can I get this fixed?

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues getting invoke-sqlcmd to work without installing SQL Server Management Studio. What I found is that the bare minimum (without SSMS) needed to run invoke-sqlcmd are three files:

Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for SQL Server® 2008 R2

Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects

Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2008 R2

found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

Then open up Powershell and enter:

```
set-alias installutil $env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil

installutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll"
installutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll"

Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerProviderSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
```

If you installed the 64-bit files you will need to run:

```
set-alias installutil $env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil

installutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll"
installutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll"

Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerProviderSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
```

Also, make sure you are using the correct version of Powershell as the 64-bit version of Powershell cannot use the 32-bit version of "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll" and "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll"